# Blank screen after upgrading to Xcode 6.1 / 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode

Is happening something strange with Xcode 6.1 / 6.2.

Until I was using Xcode 6.0, I had no strange problems.

Since I installed Xcode 6.1 and Xcode 6.2 later, when I make some changes in the storyboard, or even to the code, my app starts with a blank screen (device and simulator), randomly, for no reason. I make changes elsewhere, but the app has problems at launch.

I cleaned the folder (shift + command + K / shift + command + option + K) but nothing changes.

Is a known issue with these versions of Xcode? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: the launch images are Ok.

Comment: try check LaunchImages

Comment: launch images http://oi59.tinypic.com/2vb08et.jpg

Comment: i don't see where are your default images? You should upload images for every resolution where you need.

Comment: Yes, are placeholder. White images with black text (iphone 4, 5, 6 etc)